# What is the point of signing jwt if it can be decrypted without it

Tags: node.js, security, encryption, jwt, express-jwt

I am experimenting with [jwt](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) , and while doing some research i fount this  [JWT DECODER](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/jwtdecoder) i thought i would have to enter token and my secret key to decrypt the token .

But i was surprised see it only required token to decrypt it. What is the use of secret key if it can be decrypted without it. All user data in token will be open to anyone.

Am i missing something here ??

And my another question is how jwt helps to prevent [MITM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)

Thanks

Comment: Signing is not encryption.  Signing allows you to verify the author of a payload but does not keep the payload from being inspected, and you can do so without having access to the private key of the author.

Comment: the content can be seen by anyone with a JWS (a signed JWT), but if you verify the token validity with the secret, you can then be sure the content has not been altered, or you reject it. These tokens are made for non-sensitive data. If you want the content to be encrypted, you can use JWE, but it is more complex to use.

Answer (score 6):

The token is signed and *encoded* (not encrypted), and so the original data can be derived without need for a key. The [signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) allows the token to be verified by anyone with the public key, but the signature itself can only be generated by the entity holding the private key.

As a result of these properties, any changes to the data can be detected, and we can reliably determine who issued the token. This prevents MITM-type because the MITM does not have access to the private key, and so cannot generate a signature for the token that will pass verification.